# How to use map.get in aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I would like to get the values of object without aura iteration

```
let buttonList = tempRes.buttonList;
            var btnObj = [] ;
            if(buttonList){
                buttonList.forEach(function(button){
                    btnObj.push({
                        'label':button.Button_Label__c,
                         'details':{'label':button.Button_Label__c,'textColor':button.Button_Text_Color__c,'Icon':button.Icon__c,'shortCut':button.Shortcut_Keys__c,'bgColor':button.Background_Color__c}
                    })
                })
            }
            component.set("v.btnList",btnObj);
```

I know to get it through aura:iterator. Is there any alternative?. Please help.

Can I do something like this in aura

```
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar', {'test':123,'test2':2333});
 map1.set('bar1', 'foo00000');
 if(map1.has('bar')){
  console.log(map1.get('bar').test);
  }
```

Is this possible?

```
<aura:if istrue="map1.has('bar'))">
<button value={!map1.get('bar').test}/>
</aura:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, [there is no function in Aura to check if a `Map` contains a value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm). Instead, you will need to check for the value in your JavaScript controller or helper (similar to your example with [`Map.has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) and store the value in a way that is referenceable in your component markup.

.js controller or helper

```js
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('bar', {'test':123,'test2':2333});
map1.set('bar1', 'foo00000');
component.set('v.hasBar', map1.has('bar'));
```

.cmp

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasBar}"
    <p>true outcome</p>
</aura:if>
```

However, if you need to iterate over results that exist within the Map, you can do that too by taking `Map.values()` and putting them into an array that `<aura:iterate />` can walk over.